# Add option to select box

Tags: javascript, html

I just saw an example of a select box where you could add an option by typing an not existing option in the select box it self and by clicking a submit ,

```js
    
function myFunction()
{
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "Kiwi";
x.add(option);
}
```

so , my question is how can i change " kiwi" to any other word could the user could insert

---

i want to let the user insert the word he wants , " kiwi must include in my js ' but what about the user ? how can he do that ? i don't even know if this is the right method to add an option to select box , sorry if my question was not clear

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help] for guidance on how your question could be improved to fit StackOverflow. What have you tried? What exactly are you having trouble with? Getting text from a text field? Attaching an event listener to a button or the text field? With the code you have provide you are most of the way there.

Comment: i want to let the user  insert the word he wants , " kiwi must include in my js ' but what about the user ? how can he do that ?  i don't even know if this is the right method to add an option to select box  , sorry if my question was not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function myFunction()
{
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = document.getElementById("text").value;
x.add(option);
}
```

```css
body, button{
  font-family: consolas, sans-serif;
}
h1,h2,h3{
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1>Add Options!</h1>
<mark>Sorry, but your question was not clear enough and I could not fully understand it. Here is my best shot at answering the question.</mark>

<h2> Result </h2>


<textarea placeholder = "Type here" id = "text"></textarea>
<input type = "submit" onclick = "myFunction()">
<br>

<select id = "mySelect">


</select>
```

So first, get a textarea (`<textarea></textarea>`) and make the id = "text". If you already have a textarea or a input you can skip this step.

Then, you can put

```js
option.text = document.getElementById("text").value;
//instead of option.text = "kiwi";
```

The `.value` at the end is for inputs and textareas and tells the program what the user has inputted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab text from an input on a button click then assign that text to a new option element. Finally, append it to the select element.

To make this scaleable we are going to create a `div` to hold all our elements and assign the event listener to that element. We can then use event bubbling and the magic of the `this` keyword to get the appropriate text and assign it to the appropriate `select` element.

```js
//Find our fancy select elements
document.querySelectorAll(".fancy-select").forEach(function(fancySelect){
  //Add a click event handler - 
  //NOTE that "this" will refer to the clicked "fancy select element"
  fancySelect.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    //Check the event origingated from the button
    if(event.target.matches("button")){
      //Get the text element in "this" fancy-select element
      let textElement = this.querySelector(".addOptionText");
      //Check there is text      
      if(textElement.value !== ""){
        //Create and option element
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        //Givie it the text
        option.innerHTML = textElement.value;
        //Append it to the select
        this.querySelector("select").appendChild(option);
        //optionally select the new element
        this.querySelector("select").selectedIndex = this.querySelector("select").options.length - 1;
        //Finally empty the text box
        textElement.value = "";
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.fancy-select{display:inline-block;}
.fancy-select select {display:block; min-width:200px;}
```

```html
<div class="fancy-select">
  <input type="text" class="addOptionText"/><button type="button">+</button>
  <select>
    <option>Select 1 Option 1</option>
    <option>Select 1 Option 2</option>
    <option>Select 1 Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="fancy-select">
  <input type="text" class="addOptionText"/><button type="button">+</button>
  <select>
    <option>Select 2 Option 1</option>
    <option>Select 2 Option 2</option>
    <option>Select 2 Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```